# Accessing the disparity value in OpenCV when disparity map is type CV_8U?

Tags: c++, opencv

I saw from a previous post that when you obtain the disparity value in the disparity map in open cv with `disptype==CV_16S` you divide by `16.0`. How about when the disparity map is type `CV_8U`?

Do you have to divide by `8.0` to obtain the real disparity value? I haven't found any documentation on this particular type.

Answer (score 0):

You divide by 16 because the original disparity output of StereoSGBM 
is scaled by 16 and not because of the bit depth/disptype of the disparity.

If you use `sgbm->compute(left, right, disp);` the output disptype is `CV_16S` even if you previously initialised `disp` to be of type `CV_8U`. Therefore, using `convertTo` and dividing by `16.f` is the correct way. (If you for some reason want to modify `disp` before you use `convertTo` and `reprojectImageTo3D` then I don't know how you would get the real disparity values. It is, however, possible to `convertTo` `CV_8U` instead of `CV_32F` but the results will obviously not be exactly similar.)

Answer (score 0):

Disparity map of CV_8U  can be obtained from disparity map of CV_16S type by using  `imgDisparity16S.convertTo( imgDisparity8U, CV_8UC1, range);`

where range is calculated as`range = 255 / maxVal - minVal` and`minMaxLoc( imgDisparity16S, &minVal, &maxVal );`

So i guess the reciprocal of range i.e `1 / range` will convert CV_8U to CV_16S and then you can have actual disparity value.

P.S : I haven't tried this.